# How to transfer data from one table into another?

Tags: css, mysqli

Okay, I've 2 tables. One is called users2 and one is called user_totals. ive rows that are called clicks(impression_count), fclicks(use_count), completed_stus(completion_count). the ones in braces are the new ones in the user_totals table. Anyway I'd like to add all the ints from the first table into the second table but only if the stats in the second table are 0. also it should be added to the same user id which is id in the first table and user_id in the second. Could somebody give me a working mysqli statement to perform that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a insert with select:

```
INSERT INTO x
    (a, b, c, d)
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM y
WHERE z=2
```